# Can I program with java instead of python on my raspberry pi?

Tags: java, python, raspberry-pi

I am very new to the world of the raspberry pi and I have discovered that it takes python programming instead of java. I'm efficient in Java and I just started learning Python. Is there anyway I can program in Java on the raspberry pi?

Comment: Why wouldn't you? You know how to install a JVM, right?

Comment: Apparently, you can! https://www.raspberrypi.org/oracle-java-on-raspberry-pi/, I know python has some fancy modules for GPIO though, not sure if java will have as many tools developed.

Comment: This might be of help Java to Python [converter](https://www.varycode.com/converter.html)

Comment: really the right answer is keep learning python ... you will be able to get much more done, much more quickly in the long run .... (note there are somethings that java does better and I do understand that there are valid reasons to choose java over python, however in the context of the raspberrypi I am having a hard time picturing a project that would be better suited to java)

Comment: This may help: http://pi4j.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Raspian image you could try using this command

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-jdk
```

found on https://www.raspberrypi.org/oracle-java-on-raspberry-pi/

more info from oracle http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/raspberrypi-1704896.html